# Sql Server Management Studio Setting Login time for user

Tags: sql-server

I have created views and have to give access to new user to read only.
But i have  question abut login. Can I set a time for connection? For example: Restrict a user to only be able to login after 15:00 am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Windows Authentication for this `LOGIN` then you can have it work through Windows' built-in time-based login restrictions. If you're using SQL Authentication then you will probably have to use a SQL Agent Job that will periodically enable and disable the user's login object at a set schedule.

Answer (score 1):

> Restrict a user to only be able to login after 15:00 am?

You can use `logon trigger` for accomplish this. Here is corresponding BOL article

[Logon Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598(v=sql.105).aspx)

And here is the complete solution:

```
create trigger trg_Logon_after_15_only 
 on all server 
 for logon 
 as 
 begin 
     declare @currTime datetime = current_timestamp; 
     if original_login() = 'YourLogin' and  (cast(@currTime as time) <= '15:00:00') 
          rollback; 
 end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but it is not main solution because this trigger will effect every login and will cause performance decrease